# Can the Trump adminstration undo the Flores consent decree?

Tags: united-states, law, donald-trump, immigration, illegal-immigration

In 1997, the U.S. Department of Justice agreed to a [settlement](https://cliniclegal.org/sites/default/files/attachments/flores_v._reno_settlement_agreement_1.pdf) in a case called Flores vs. Reno.  Among other things, this settlement prohibits unaccompanied children who have crossed the border from being held in federal detention facilities for longer than 20 days.  In 2016, the Ninth Circuit Court of Appeals [ruled](https://cdn.ca9.uscourts.gov/datastore/opinions/2016/07/06/15-56434.pdf) that this 20 day prohibition applies to both accompanied minors (children who came along with family members) and unaccompanied minors.

This has all become relevant now because of the Trump Administration's new "zero tolerance" policy and the family separations that have resulted from it.  Many Republicans, including Trump Administration officials, have argued that separating families is necessary because if a parent requests asylum, it usually takes longer than 20 days, so under the Flores settlement either the government has to let both the parent and child go after 20 days (which Republicans deride as "catch and release"), or detain the parent and release the child in which case they're separated.  So they're demanding that legislation be passed overturning the Flores settlement and allowing the government to detain parents and children together for longer than 20 days (and demanding various border security measures in return).

Now this is a bit of a red herring, because the "zero tolerance" policy would separate families with or without the Flores settlement.  But my question is, does the Trump Administration have the power to undo the Flores settlement on its own?  Can the Executive branch break court settlements it's entered into, or does it require legislation to break a court settlement?

Comment: @Brythan What the zero-tolerance policy does is it prosecutes everyone who crosses the border illegally. And if a parent is prosecuted, they'll be sent to federal prison and separated from their kids, since kids can't be in federal prison. "But migrants who’ve been referred for criminal prosecution get sent to a federal jail and brought before a federal judge a few weeks later to see if they’ll get prison time. That’s where the separation happens — because you can’t be kept with your children in federal jail." https://www.vox.com/2018/6/11/17443198/children-immigrant-families-separated-parents

Comment: @Brythan So even if the Flores settlement was repealed tomorrow, as long as you have criminal prosecutions of everyone who comes illegally, you'd still have separation of families.

Comment: Except that immigration prosecutions generally result in deportation (example [source](https://www.houstonchronicle.com/news/houston-texas/houston/article/Trump-pressing-for-mass-criminalization-of-11962046.php)), not jail time.  Under the current system, it is easier to deport a convict (even of a misdemeanor) than someone claiming asylum.  The deported parents can of course take their children with them.  The Trump proposal is that the entire family's asylum request or citizenship claim be reviewed as a unit and the entire family be deported (or accepted) as a unit.

Comment: @Brythan there are already reports that parents are deported without their children (e.g. https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/17/us/immigration-deported-parents.html), so that does not seem to be true.

Comment: @Brythan The issue is not the sentence issued in the criminal trial.  The issue is that under the zero-tolerance policy, a parent who requests asylum has to stay in federal prison awaiting trial while seperated from their child.  That is the thing that people are objecting to.

Comment: Right, but under the Trump proposal, they wouldn't prosecute people generally.  They only prosecute people because that is the shortest path to deporting them.  If there was a system that allowed them to deport without prosecuting them or detaining them separately from their children, then it would still be zero tolerance from their perspective but would avoid separating parents and children.

Comment: @Brythan We're not talking about what Trump wants, we're talking about the policy as it currently exists.  The current policy causes seperation of families, and what causes the policy to separate families has nothing to do with the Flores settlement.  The Flores settlement might be what motivated Trump to enact the policy he has enacted, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @Brythan If there was no zero-tolerance policy, then one might reasonably argue "We can either release both the parent and the child or detain the parent and release the child.  The former risks the parent not showing up, so we have to do the latter.  It's all the Flores settlement's fault."  But that's not what's going on.  These are orthogonal issues.  If criminal prosecution is better because it's quicker at deportation than a civil proceeding, then it would be quicker regardless of whether the Flores settlement existed.  So Flores really is a red herring.

Comment: If there was no Flores consent decree, then one might reasonably argue "We can either keep the family in detention or prosecute the adults, separating them from the children.  The latter is entirely at the government's discretion.  It's the zero-tolerance policy's fault."  But that's not what's going on.  These issues are directly related.  The Flores consent decree blocks the desired path, so they are working a different path.  Note that even without the zero-tolerance policy, they would still have to release the children at twenty days.  So the zero-tolerance party really is a red herring.

Comment: "the Ninth Circuit" -Yes.

Comment: @Keshav, I don't understand the relevance of your point that "[criminal prosecution] would be quicker regardless of whether the Flores settlement existed". Isn't the issue whether or not children can be detained with their parents while the parents are detained, rather than how long (past 20 days) the parents are detained?

Comment: @KyleStrand I was responding to Brythan’s statement “They only prosecute people because that is the shortest path to deporting them.”

Comment: Does that somehow support your argument that these are "orthogonal issues", then? Wouldn't Flores still require separating parents from kids even if the parents were detained for civil proceedings? The point is that *without* Flores, the parents could elect to keep their children in detention with them.

Comment: @KyleStrand My point to Brythonic is that the Flores settlement does not constitute a justification for the zero-tolerance policy. With Flores in place, you basically have three options: 1. Criminally prosecute the parent and release the child 2. Detain the parent and release the child 3. Release both the parent and child. The decision to choose option 2 rather than option 3 might be justified by saying “Under Flores the only way to make sure the parent shows up for their deportation proceeding is option 2 so Flores is to blame.” But you cant use Flores to justify option 1 rather than option 2

Comment: Ah. I don't think anyone is claiming that Flores justifies zero tolerance. The problem is that without Flores, enforcing the law (with zero tolerance for those breaking it) would not require separating kids from their parents.

Comment: @KyleStrand Without Flores, the zero tolerance policy would still separate parents from kids.  Because what the zero tolerance policy criminally prosecutes all parents who enter illegally, and that separates parents from kids because if the parent is criminally prosecuted then they go to federal prison awaiting trial, and kids can't be in federal prison.  See my answer here: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/31592/1953

Comment: @KyleStrand By the way it may be helpful to think about four scenarios: A. Flores settlement and zero tolerance policy B. Flores settlement without zero tolerance policy C. Zero tolerance policy without Flores settlement D, Neither Flores settlement nor zero tolerance policy. Under scenario A (what we have now), you have to separate parents and children. Under scenario B (what we had before) you can detain the parent & release the child or release both. Under scenario C, you have to separate parents and children. Under scenario D, you detain both, detain parent & release child or release both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79061/discussion-between-kyle-strand-and-keshav-srinivasan).

Answer (score 6):

It depends exactly what you mean.

Can the Donald Trump administration unilaterally end the Flores [consent decree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consent_decree)?  No.  The consent decree is part of an agreement between parties.  The federal government is just one of the parties.  A modification would require agreement among all involved parties and the approval of the court.  There is no evidence that the other parties are interested in removing the consent decree.

Could the Trump administration ask the courts to remove the consent decree?  Yes, but there is no guarantee that the courts would do so.  The government would have to establish that the consent decree or its side effects are more undesirable than the wrong that the consent decree was created to address.  This is generally a high bar, as the government consented to be limited by the decree.  It was part of an agreement to settle a suit.  Ending or even modifying it would therefore give the other party room to argue that they should no longer have to comply with their responsibilities under the settlement.

It is for this reason that people who advocate an end or modification of the consent decree look to Congress for legislative action.  If the underlying law on which the suit proceeded were changed, that would invalidate both sides of the settlement.  They could replace it wholesale with a new system, set forth in legislation.

Comment: [Even if Flores didn’t exist, the government would be very constrained in how many family units it can accommodate. ICE has only about 3,000 family spaces in shelters. It is also limited in its overall space at the border, which is overwhelmed by the ongoing influx. This means that — whatever the Trump administration would prefer to do — many adults are still swiftly released.](https://www.nationalreview.com/2018/05/illegal-immigration-enforcement-separating-kids-at-border/#slide-1)

Comment: @KDog are you Rich Lowry? If not, I think you might have to provide a cite for the quote you've cut and pasted from https://www.nationalreview.com/2018/05/illegal-immigration-enforcement-separating-kids-at-border/#slide-1

Comment: Ran out of characters